# Reduction expression having $\sec(x)$ and $\tan(x)$ terms

Tags: indefinite-integrals, reduction-formula

> If $\displaystyle I_{m,n}=\int \sec^{2n}(x)\tan^{m}(x)dx, $ where $m\geq2,n\geq 1$ and $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$

> Then prove that $\displaystyle I_{m,n}=\frac{\sec^{2n}(x)\tan^{m-1}(x)}{2n}-\frac{m-1}{2n}I_{m-2,n+1}$

From $\displaystyle I_{m,n}=\int \sec^{2n}(x)\tan^{m}(x)dx$

$\displaystyle I_{m,n}=\int \sec^{2n-2}(x)\tan^{m}(x)\sec^2(x)dx$

Using integration by parts

$\displaystyle I_{m,n}=[\sec^{2n-2}(x)\int \tan^{m}(x)\sec^2(x)dx-\int (\sec^{2n-2}(x))'\int\tan^{m}(x)\sec^2(x)dx$

Put $\tan(x)=t$ and $\sec^2(x)dx=dt$

$\displaystyle I_{m,n}=\sec^{2n-2}(x)\frac{\tan^{m+1}(x)}{m+1}-\frac{2n-2}{m+1}\int\sec^{2n-3}(x)\sec(x)\tan(x)\tan^{m-1}(x)dx$

$\displaystyle I_{m,n}=\frac{\sec^{2n-2}(x)\tan^{m+1}(x)}{m+1}-\frac{2n-2}{m+1}I_{m+2,n-1}$

But I am not getting my original proving expression.please have a look.

Comment: Maybe try another integration by part ? The one you used is not the only possibility and seem to go in the opposite direction that the one intended (increasing in $m$, decreasing in $n$, instead of the opposite).

Comment: Alternatively, by reversing the formula you got at the end you can check that you have indeed found (and thus proven) the right formula, for the index $(m+2, n-1)$ instead of $(m, n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sec^{2n}x=2n\sec^{2n-1}x\sec x \tan x =2n\sec^{2n}x\tan x$$
Hence, you have:
$$ I_{m,n}=\int \sec^{2n}x\tan^{m}xdx=\frac{1}{2n}\int 2n\sec^{2n}x\tan x\tan^{m-1}xdx= $$
$$=\frac{\sec^{2n}x\tan^{m-1}x}{2n}-\frac{m-1}{2n}\int\sec^{2n}x\tan^{m-2}x\sec^2xdx=$$ $$=\frac{\sec^{2n}x\tan^{m-1}x}{2n}-\frac{m-1}{2n} I_{m-2,n+1} $$